# Is light bending around my finger?

Tags: light

I was hoping that astronomy enthusiasts/scientists would help me out with a simple question about light. Hold your outstretched hand up to any bright light source (the sun, or even a light bulb) so that the light is completely blocked by at least one finger, and then slowly move your finger to the side until the light just peeks around. **There seems to be a glow when you do this, and I was wondering what causes this.**

Is the light bending around my finger from some sort of diffraction? What's going on?

Comment: That's by [refraction][1] and [light scattering][2]. [Diffraction][3] occurs, but is too weak to be noticeable.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction
  [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_scattering
  [3]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics.